# How to update a hash partitioned column in Oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle12c, database-partitioning

I have a table that is partitioned by hash on a column.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(
  ACCOUNT_NUMBER VARCHAR(20)
)
PARTITION BY HASH (ACCOUNT_NUMBER)
PARTITIONS 16
```

Now, I want to update the `account_number` column itself in the table because of certain requirements.
As this column is partitioned, I'm not able to issue an update command on the table like

`Update test set account_number = new_value`

as it results to the below error:

> **Error is**: ORA-14402: UPDATING PARTITION WOULD CAUSE PARTITION CHANGE.

Row movement is set to disable for the table.

The one way I know is to enable row movement but I also want to explore other options.

Could you please advise me on how to solve this?

Comment: Can you define "unable".  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?  What is the command you are using?  My wild guess is that the table disallows row movement and you need to alter it to enable row movement before you do the update.  But that's a guess without more information.

Comment: I have updated my question with updates.
 Please take a look.

Comment: Why don't you want to enable row movement?  What would another option look like?  I suppose you could create a new table where account_number was not the partition key but that hardly seems like a sensible thing to do absent a much more compelling problem.